# MVC append partial view to existing kendo pop up window

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-mvc, kendo-window

I created a kendo pop up window that loads a dropdown selection from the controller in the contents. I also added a change event that gets the id of the selected index and pass it to the controller and returns a partial view with textboxes that might change based on selection, so the creation of textboxes needs to be dynamic. 
I tried adding Html.Partial(_myPartialView), but the results are not rendering. What am I doing wrong?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
  .Name("userSetupWindow")
  .AppendTo("#useAcct")
  .Width(600)
  .Height(600)
  .Scrollable(false)
  .Modal(true)
  .Title("New Setup")
  .Actions(actions => actions.Refresh().Close())
  .Draggable()
  .Content("<section id='CreateLink' class = 'saveNewDialog-screen'>" +
           "<div class='saveNewLinkDialog'  style='border: none;' >" +
           "<div style='border: none;'>" +
        "<table>" +
               "<tr style='height: 30px;'>" +
                 "<td style='width: 30%; vertical-align: top;'>" +
                  "<div id='divAccounts' class ='createNew'> " +
                  "<label id='lbList' for='createNew' class='CreateNew-Label'>Select New</label>&nbsp;" +
                   Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                  .Name("userList")
                  .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("GetUsers", "UserAcctMgmt")
                  .Data("getSelectedId")
                  .Type(HttpVerbs.Post)))
                  .DataTextField("UserName")
                  .DataValueField("Id")
                  .Value("Id")
                  .SelectedIndex(0)
                  .Events(events => events.DataBound("onDropDownDataBound"))
                  .Events(events => events.Change("onSelect")) +
                  "</div>" +
                  "</td>" +
                  "</tr>" +
                  "<tr style='height: 30px;'>" +
                  "<td>&nbsp;</td>" +
                  "<td>" +
                  "<div id='divButtons' class='createNew-buttonContainer'>" +
                        "<button id='createNewLink-cancel' class='k-button saveNewButtons' >Cancel</button>&nbsp;" +
                        "<button id='createNewLink-save' class='k-button saveNewButtons'>Save</button>" +
                  "</div>" +
                  "</td>" +
                  "</tr>" +
                  "<tr style='height: 80px;>" +
                  "<td>" +
                  "<div id='div-textboxes'>" +
                Html.Partial(_dynamicPartialView)
                  "</div>" +
                  "</td>" +
                  "</tr>" +
          "</table>" +
                "</div>" +
                "</div>" +
                "</section>'"
  ).Events(events => events.Close("onPopupClose"))
```

In the controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetUserFields(string Id)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Id))
        {
            var fields = GetuserFields(int.Parse(Id));

            var model = new FieldModel
            {
                Fields = fields 
            };

            return PartialView("_dynamicPartialView", model);
        }

        return null;
}
```

Jquery works, and it takes me to the partial view

```
    function onSelect(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selectedId = this.dataItem(e.item).id;

        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("GetUserFields", "UserModel")",
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify({ Id: selectedId }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        });
    }
```

Here is the partial view (_dynamicPartialView)

```
@model Models.UserFieldModel
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

@if (Model != null)
{
foreach (var item in Model.UserFields)
{
<p>@item.FieldName</p>

if (item.FieldType.ToString().ToUpper() == "TEXTBOX")
{
    if (item.IsCaseSensitiveField)
    {
        @(Html.Kendo().TextBox()
                .Name("caseSensitive")
        )
     }
    else
    {
        @(Html.Kendo().TextBox()
                .Name("textInput")
        )
    }
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't implemented your code, so this is just a guess from interpreting what you have.  It looks like you're not doing anything with the response from the call to get the partial view.  In your javascript onSelect method, there is nothing happening when the call succeeded.  This means that you are calling the GetUserFields action on the controller, and it is returning the rendered partial view, but you javascript onSelect method is effectively ignoring the result.

You probably need to add some logic in the success part of your ajax call.

```
function onSelect(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectedId = this.dataItem(e.item).id;

    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("GetUserFields", "UserModel")",
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({ Id: selectedId }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
        success: function(){
            // attach the response to the existing DOM
        }
    });
}
```